# PDF view not rendered in IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf, cross-browser

I am trying to display a PDF in a dialog using blob url set to angularjs' scope variable. This works perfectly in case of google chrome, but it doesn't seem to work in IE, Edge or Firefox (latest version).

*C# controller:*

```
HttpResponseMessage result = null;

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileContent);

result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");

result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;

result.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);

return result;
```

-> Here 'fileContent' is a byte Array.

*Angular Controller:*

```
var data = $.param({
                ID: fileRowID
            });            

$http.post('api/getFileData', data, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).success(function (response) {
    var file = new Blob([(data)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $scope.fileContent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL); 
})
```

*HTML:*

```
< object style="width:100%; height:600px" type="application/pdf" data="{{fileContent}}" >< /object >
```

This piece of code works perfect only in Chrome. `<object>` and `<embed>` doesn't work with IE, Edge or Firefox. I also tried `<iframe>` but the blob url doesn't work with the 'src' attribute of the `<iframe>`. I don't want to use 'msSaveBlob' or 'msSaveOrOpenBlob' as the requirement is to display the PDF and not to download.

Comment: I am still left with no solution on this.. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Is it solved? I have the same problem.